# From jTextField to INSERT sql

Tags: java, jdbc, jtextfield, numberformatexception, parseint

I would like to thank you guys in advance for taking the time. I'm trying to insert the values that entered in jtextfield into a table using sql statement but i'm keep getting a bunch of errors.

Listener :

```
private void jTextField1FocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
    name = jTextField1.getText();
}                                     

private void jTextField2FocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
    username = jTextField2.getText();
}                                     

private void jTextField3FocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
    String pword = jTextField2.getText();
    password = Integer.parseInt(pword);
    //the convertion is essential because the password column in the table is defined as integer
}                                     

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    register regis = new register(name, username, password);
    regis.registerUser();
}
```

INSERT :

```
public class register {

    public String name;
    public String username;
    public Integer password;

    public register(String nm, String uname, Integer passw) {
        name = nm;
        username = uname;
        password = passw;
    }

    public void registerUser(){

        try { 
            String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/fypDB";
            String uname = "uname";
            String pword = "123456";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uname, pword );
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            String SQL = "INSERT INTO LOGIN VALUES('"+username+"',"+password+")";
            stmt.executeUpdate( SQL );
        } catch (SQLException err){
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The LOGIN table has only 2 columns so i just ignored the "name" variable.

Since i cannot upload the image i'll describe the interface. textfield 1 and 2 entered "test13" and 3rd textfield which is for password is entered "10" and then register button was clicked.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "test13"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at Interface.Register.jTextField3FocusLost(Register.java:137)
at Interface.Register.access$200(Register.java:15)
at Interface.Register$3.focusLost(Register.java:63)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.focusLost(AWTEventMulticaster.java:230)
at java.awt.Component.processFocusEvent(Component.java:6419)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6283)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:995)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:661)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4754)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `jTextField3FocusLost` you are reading from `jTextField2` instead of `jTextField3`. So the password is being read as `test13`.

Few notes:

- Name your class to start with an uppercase letter.
- Try using prepared statements instead of SQL statements like `"INSERT INTO LOGIN VALUES('"+username+"',"+password+")";`.
- Avoid variables that start with an uppercase.
- Always close a SQL connection and statements after using them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You were missing quotes around the password value.

```
String SQL = "INSERT INTO LOGIN VALUES('"+username+"','"+password+"')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You take the value from the wrong Field.
You have to change:

```
String pword = jTextField2.getText();
```

to

```
String pword = jTextField3.getText();
```